# sql - max from group flag setter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I m trying to achieve flag setting for the condition in my table below

```
p_id      mon_year      e_id     flag  
----      ---------     -----    -----
 1          2011/11       20       0
 1          2011/11       21       1
 1          2012/01       22       1
 1          2012/02       23       0
 1          2012/02       24       0
 1          2012/02       25       1
 2          2011/11       28       0
 2          2011/11       29       1
 2          2012/01       30       1
```

grouping by p_id,e_id and mon_year, the flag is set for the last value in the month.

I m confused how can i achieve this

I tried to achieved this by using row_number and partition to seperate out the value. By still looking for to achieved

Output by using row_number query , i have got is as below:

Grouping by

```
p_id      mon_year      e_id     row
----      ---------     -----    -----
 1          2011/11       20       1
 1          2011/11       21       2
 1          2012/01       22       1
 1          2012/02       23       1
 1          2012/02       24       2
 1          2012/02       25       3
 2          2011/11       28       1
 2          2011/11       29       2
 2          2012/01       30       1
```

Max of this value would set the flag column. But i m really bugged how to achieve it. Any help would be useful.

Thanks !!

Comment: What do you mean by "achieve flag setting for the condition"?

Comment: you could use your partition by trick but change the order to desc - then instead of max, you want the first one, which will always be 1.

Comment: Flag is set (1) only for the last mon_year value provided p_id is same and e_id is different.

Comment: Thanks a lot , JohnLBevan it works the best  !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're going for. . .  The output exactly matches your example:

```
declare @t table (p_id int, [year] int, [month] int,  [day] int)
insert @t select 1, 2011, 11, 20
    union select 1, 2011, 11, 21
    union select 1, 2012, 01, 22
    union select 1, 2012, 02, 23
    union select 1, 2012, 02, 24
    union select 1, 2012, 02, 25
    union select 2, 2011, 11, 28
    union select 2, 2011, 11, 29
    union select 2, 2012, 01, 30

select p_id, [year], [month], [day] 
, case when r=1 then 1 else 0 end flag
from
(
    select p_id, [year], [month], [day]
    , row_number() over (partition by p_id, [year], [month] order by [day] desc) r
    from @t
) x
order by  p_id, [year], [month], [day]
```

Output:

```
p_id    year    month   day     flag
1       2011    11      20      0
1       2011    11      21      1
1       2012    1       22      1
1       2012    2       23      0
1       2012    2       24      0
1       2012    2       25      1
2       2011    11      28      0
2       2011    11      29      1
2       2012    1       30      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering by descending. In that way, you don't have to look for maximum ROW_NUMBER but when ROW_NUMBER is 1 ;)

Something like this (I didn't completely understand what you want to achieve, so this is probably not 100% accurate):

```
WITH r_MyTable
AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mon_year ORDER BY p_id, e_id DESC) AS GroupRank
    FROM MyTable
)
UPDATE r_MyTable
SET flag = CASE WHEN GroupRank = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use max statement on e_id to get last value for the month, code is below:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmptest') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tmptest

    SELECT
        *
    INTO
        #tmptest
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  '1' p_id,          '2011/11' mon_year,       '20' e_id,      '0' flag UNION ALL
        SELECT  '1',          '2011/11',       '21',       '1' UNION ALL
        SELECT  '1',          '2012/01',       '22',       '1' UNION ALL
        SELECT  '1',          '2012/02',       '23',       '0' UNION ALL
        SELECT  '1',          '2012/02',       '24',       '0' UNION ALL
        SELECT  '1',          '2012/02',       '25',       '1' UNION ALL
        SELECT  '2',          '2011/11',       '28',       '0' UNION ALL
        SELECT  '2',          '2011/11',       '29',       '1' UNION ALL
        SELECT  '2', '2012/01',       '30',       '1' 
    ) as tmp

    SELECT
        tmptest.*
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                MAX(e_id) e_id
                ,p_id
                ,mon_year
            FROM 
                #tmptest
            GROUP BY
                p_id,mon_year
        ) tblLastValueEID
    INNER JOIN
        #tmptest tmptest
    ON
        tmptest.p_id = tblLastValueEID.p_id
    AND
        tmptest.mon_year = tblLastValueEID.mon_year
    AND
        tmptest.e_id = tblLastValueEID.e_id
```